# Reading files and writing to database in django

Tags: python, database, django, file, file-io

I have a Django app that opens a file, continuously reads it, and at the same time writes data to a Postgres database.  My issue is that whenever I open a file,

```
file = open(filename, 'r')
```

I am unable to also create new things in the database,

```
Message.objects.create_message(sys, msg)
```

That should create a database entry with two strings.  However, nothing seems to happen and I am presented with no errors :( If I decide to close the file, `file.close()`, before I write to the database everything is fine.  My problem is that I need that file open to create my objects.  Does anyone have a solution for this?  Thanks.

**EDIT**

Here's some more of my code.  Basically I have the following snippet following the end of a file and then writing to the database as it gets information.

```
file.seek(0,2)         
while True:
  line = file.readline()
  if not line:
    time.sleep(1)
    continue
  Message.objects.create_message(sys, line)
```

**EDIT 2**

Got this to work finally but I'm not sure why.  I'd love to understand why this worked:

```
str1ng = line[0:len(line)-1]
Message.objects.create_message(sys, str1ng)
```

Some how there is a difference between that string and the string gathered from file.readline().
Any ideas?

Comment: You should post more of your code.  From these snippets it's not possible to tell what's going on.

Comment: it sounds like the idea of messagin through the file itself is whats getting you into trouble here.  can you get the io stream from whoever is writing the file in another way?  what about renaimng the file, using that copy until done, then wash rinse repeat.?

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
file = open(filename, 'r')
fileContents = file.read()
file.close()
```

Comment: That worked but I need to keep the file open since it is being added to while I am reading it.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is doing that every x seconds.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried linecache? Something like this might work (not tested).

```
import linecache

i = 0
go = True
file = ...
while (go == True):
   out = linecache.getline(file,i)
   ...process out...
   i = i+1
   if i % 100 == 0:
       # check for cache update every 100 lines
       linecache.checkcache(file)
   if ( some eof condition):
       go = False
linecache.clearcache()
```

Comment: Gave this approach a try but unfortunately the same problem occurs.  Now I'm confused.

Comment: It appears as though your system can only have a single open file handle at a time. What are you using?